# how to check if the fetch variable has data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, fetch-api

```
  function Login() {

 const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setpassword] = useState("");

  const [users, setUser] = useState([]);

  function login() {
    fetch(
      "http://116.202.231.219:8069/Restaurant/Login_Updated?Cont4=" +
        email +
        "&Pswd=" +
        password
    ).then((result) => {
      result.json().then((resp) => {
        // console.warn(resp)
        setUser(resp);
        console.log(resp);
        });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
      <h1>Login Page</h1>
      <br />
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <input
        type="password"
        className="form-control"
        onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <br />
      <button onClick={login} className="btn btn-primary">
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

now I want to check that if the data being fetched is the same as the data being put in the inputs so I am trying using "IF" but the "RESP" variable is not global I mean that it is not working with "IF". So can you guys help me how to do a check that the Email pass is equal to the Email pass from the API.

As you can see that API is getting the cont4 and pass from the input tags and giving back the objects in return but I am not able to run the success check on this API that if it returns object go to dashboard else throw alert of error

Comment: `resp` is a single string?

Comment: `resp` is an object

Comment: Just use `if-else` after serializing response to `json` inside `then` callback

Comment: I did not understand what is meant by serializing I am really sorry it is my first time playing with API`s

Comment: This does not answer your question, but is just something I wanted to point out. Having `.then()` inside of a `.then()` callback is an anti-patern. Use `.then((result) => result.json()).then((resp) => ...)`. See: [MDN Using Promises - Common mistakes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#common_mistakes)

Answer (score 0):

```js
import axios from 'axios';
//add axios in your project

function Login() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setpassword] = useState("");
    const [users, setUser] = useState({});


    loginHandel = () => {
        const url = `http://116.202.231.219:8069/Restaurant/Login_Updated?Cont4=${email}&Pswd=${password}`
        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            //check the res if its getting the correct data or not?
            //restructure accordingly
            console.log(res);
            const persons = res;
            if ((persons?.email === email) && (persons?.password === password)) {
                //perform any thing here
                setUser(persons);
            } else {
                console.log("User email and passwoed mismatched!")
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            //handel your error
            console.log(err);
        })
    }

    return (
        <div className="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3">
            <h1>Login Page</h1>
            <br />
            <form>
                
            </form>
            <input
                type="text"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br />
            <br />
            <input
                type="password"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(e) => setpassword(e.target.value)}
            />
            <br />
            <br />
            <button onClick={loginHandel} className="btn btn-primary">
                Login
         </button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The API is giving the data of the user in the API i am adding the email and pass by variables i just want that when the email or pass is wrong then it should give error or else go to other page. Hope you can understand what I want

Comment: do you want a check after api success, whether the response username and passed user name are correct ?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I want

Comment: I have edited the code with some assumptions if this is also not clear then give the total file,

Comment: I am sorry i have edited my question can you please take a look at it again this time I will add the API too

Comment: I have edited the answer yesterday, check it. If it works

Comment: it still is not working for me because in the API I do not have email and password as the data in API I want to check if the status is 200 then push to another page else give it error